# How did the Twitter web app achieve such a native feel?

Tags: html, web

If any of you guys can pull up the twitter.com web app on your iPhone's, you will notice how the address bar dissapears and becomes replaced with the Twitter header bar. You can scroll the content with elasticity but the Twitter header bar stays in place just like with a native app. How did these guys  do it?

Update: Looks like they changed their web app. Before, it was kind of like Sencha. I am trying to create the effect without using the full library. Take a look at this:

http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html

Answer (score 0):

They didn't hide the address bar permanently. They are using Mobile Safari's behavior of scrolling down causes the address bar to scroll with the page. What they did was scroll the page down, probably using [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollBy) so the address bar "disappears" (just like it does on any other page). If you fiddle with the page, you can scroll all the way back up to the top again.

[image]

Comment: Looks like they changed their web app. Before, it was kind of like Sencha. I am trying to create the effect without using the full library. Take a look at this: 

http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html